# Free memory using QFuture on cancel thread

Tags: c++, qt, qfuture, qfuturewatcher

I am writing a program that uses `QtConcurrent` to start threads. In my case, I use it to render a QGraphicsView when I use the mouse scroll.

I am starting the threads using the following code:

```
if (future.isRunning()) {
    future.cancel();
}

future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&AeVectorLayer::render, renderparams, pos);
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

When the thread is finished I catch the signal `finished` with a `QfutureWatcher`.

This is my render function:

```
QList<AeGraphicsItem*> AeVectorLayer::render(Ae::renderParams renderparams, int pos)
{
    AeVectorHandler *coso = new AeVectorHandler();
    coso->openDataset(AeLayer::absoluteFilePath);
    coso->setTransformCoordinates(myEPSG);
    QList<AeGraphicsItem*> bla = coso->getItems(renderparams.sceneRect.x(), 
    renderparams.sceneRect.y(), renderparams.sceneRect.width(), 
    renderparams.sceneRect.height(), renderparams.zoom, color, this);
    for (int i = 0; i < bla.size(); i++)
        bla.at(i)->setZValue((qreal)pos);
    delete coso;
    return bla;
}
```

As you can see, I have a `QList<QGraphicsItem*>` in my render function. How can I destroy this list when the future is cancelled? I undestand that in my code I am redefining the `future` variable but I do not know how to avoid it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#cancel) the `QFuture` returned by `QtConcurrent::run` can *not* be canceled.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, i know this. But when you use the cancel() method you can recived a Canceled() event from QFutureWatcher when the thread is finished. My problem is that i lost the reference to the canceled thread and them i can`t recive this event. In this event i could then delete the QList and avoid the memory problem.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Who or what is responsible for the ownership of the `AeGraphicsItem *` items in `bla`?  Also, why is `coso` allocated on the free store rather than on the stack?

Comment: @G.M.  `coso` allocated on the free store because is only used to open a shapefile (*.shp) with OGR and get my the list of Geometries of him transformed to a QGraphicsItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop trying to manually manage memory and instead use a smart pointer that fits your use case. Because you use move-unaware `QFuture`, you will need an `std::shared_ptr`. Once the `QFuture`/`QFutureWatcher`s go out of scope, and you hold no more `shared_ptr` instances, the resource will be deleted. So in your case your `render` function should return a `QList<std::shared_ptr<AeGraphicsItem>>`. Be careful when you transfer ownership from the `shared_ptr`s to e.g. a `QGraphicsScene`: you must `release` from the `shared_ptr` on ownership transfer.

Note that your `isRunning` check followed by `cancel` is fundamentally flawed: the future could be running when you call `isRunning` but be finished by the time you call `cancel`. If you want to cancel it, just call `cancel`. Also note that you cannot meaningfully cancel `QFuture`s returned by `QtConcurrent::run` so what you're doing is very very wrong in and of itself.

Comment: I try use this but was impossible run well the program. I decided use a class that inherit from QThread and implement my own Cancel() method. Thanks for your help.